# random sampling and probability

Tags: random, probability, sampling

Sorry in advance since my question is more statistics than programming. But, I need the answer for further implementations. 
Consider that we have N records which X of them has specific features. We randomly select n records from N (sampling without replacement). What is the probability of appearing each of the X records in the sample n? OR how small would X get when it comes to the smaller group of n?

For example: N = 40,000,000 X = 20,000 n = 25,000,000

Comment: I think this is probably isomorphic to one of those red and green balls problems that are found in probability textbooks. In any event I think stats.stackexchange.com might have more to say about it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about statistics, not programming.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it an example of [Hypergeometric Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution)?

A random variable X follows the hypergeometric distribution if its probability mass function (pmf) is given by

P(X=k) = C(K, k)*C(N-K, n-k)/C(N, n)

where

- N is the population size,
- K is the number of success states in the population,
- n is the number of draws,
- k is the number of observed successes,
- C(a, b) is a binomial coefficient.